# Cannot get my meteor app to connect to my server. Shows "connected" briefly, goes to "connecting" and "waiting"

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I am able to connect my Samsung Galaxy Prevail to my dev box, on the same LAN, run "meteor run android-device", and have my app launch on the phone and Meteor.status().status reports "Connected".  The app runs fine.

But when I use "mup" to deploy to my server, (and I can run the app on my server fine in the browser), and I run:

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server http://mymeteorappdomain.com --debug
```

I see the "Connected" for a couple seconds, but it switches to "Connecting" then "Waiting", and stays there.  I notice that the debug output line near the bottom about "restartServer" seems to coincide (visually) with the change from "Connected" to "Connecting", but I don't understand what Cordova is doing there, nor what "restartServer" does or why there should be any restarting of anything.

So the app launches but I cannot, for example, log in (with ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 and accounts-password) or otherwise do much of anything in the app.

I am developing on Ubuntu 14.04 and deploying to my Digital Ocean droplet, also running Ubuntu 14.04.

Here is the complete debug output (never mind the actual domain name):

```
Installing app on device...
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS
Command finished with error code 0: /home/fugbert/www/dev/m.myapp.com/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run --device
I20150618-09:17:47.918(-7) (android:meteor_cordova_loader.js:12) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Error reading version file Error: Failed to resolve entry: file:///data/data/com.idbzpo1upqh87wp5no3r/files/meteor/version
I20150618-09:17:47.920(-7) (android:meteor_cordova_loader.js:12) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Couldn't load from the manifest, falling back to the bundled assets.
I20150618-09:17:48.001(-7) (android:meteor_cordova_loader.js:12) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Loading from url: http://meteor.local
I20150618-09:17:52.111(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /81094d8fd7495646a6359f4dcfd57bd3f223ee39.js
I20150618-09:17:52.133(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /0045083fdb0aae9cfdd7bc8624d6d600f54d0f32.css
I20150618-09:17:52.140(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/mizzao_bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
I20150618-09:17:52.155(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/mizzao_bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
I20150618-09:17:52.161(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/mizzao_bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
I20150618-09:17:52.169(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/mizzao_bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
I20150618-09:17:52.175(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/mrt_x-editable-bootstrap3/lib/bootstrap3-editable/img/clear.png
I20150618-09:17:52.180(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/mrt_x-editable-bootstrap3/lib/bootstrap3-editable/img/loading.gif
I20150618-09:17:52.187(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/mrt_footable/lib/css/fonts/footable.eot
I20150618-09:17:52.195(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/mrt_footable/lib/css/fonts/footable.svg
I20150618-09:17:52.204(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/mrt_footable/lib/css/fonts/footable.ttf
I20150618-09:17:52.211(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/mrt_footable/lib/css/fonts/footable.woff
I20150618-09:17:52.214(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/fortawesome_fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
I20150618-09:17:52.218(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/fortawesome_fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
I20150618-09:17:52.223(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/fortawesome_fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
I20150618-09:17:52.229(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/fortawesome_fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
I20150618-09:17:52.232(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/ryw_blog/public/default-user.png
I20150618-09:17:52.239(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/ryw_blog/client/stylesheets/images/remove.png
I20150618-09:17:52.243(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/ryw_blog/client/stylesheets/images/link.png
I20150618-09:17:52.247(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/ryw_blog/client/stylesheets/images/unlink.png
I20150618-09:17:52.251(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/ryw_blog/client/stylesheets/images/resize-bigger.png
I20150618-09:17:52.255(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /packages/ryw_blog/client/stylesheets/images/resize-smaller.png
I20150618-09:17:52.258(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /favicon.ico
I20150618-09:17:52.262(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /robots.txt
I20150618-09:17:52.266(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:183) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) start downloading /index.html
I20150618-09:17:52.350(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/ryw_blog/client/stylesheets/images/remove.png
I20150618-09:17:52.365(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/mrt_footable/lib/css/fonts/footable.svg
I20150618-09:17:52.370(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/mizzao_bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
I20150618-09:17:52.383(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/ryw_blog/public/default-user.png
I20150618-09:17:52.387(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/ryw_blog/client/stylesheets/images/resize-smaller.png
I20150618-09:17:52.410(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /index.html
I20150618-09:17:52.435(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/ryw_blog/client/stylesheets/images/link.png
I20150618-09:17:52.453(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/ryw_blog/client/stylesheets/images/unlink.png
I20150618-09:17:52.453(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/mrt_x-editable-bootstrap3/lib/bootstrap3-editable/img/clear.png
I20150618-09:17:52.454(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/mrt_footable/lib/css/fonts/footable.woff
I20150618-09:17:52.458(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/mrt_x-editable-bootstrap3/lib/bootstrap3-editable/img/loading.gif
I20150618-09:17:52.466(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/mrt_footable/lib/css/fonts/footable.ttf
I20150618-09:17:52.468(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /favicon.ico
I20150618-09:17:52.469(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/ryw_blog/client/stylesheets/images/resize-bigger.png
I20150618-09:17:52.481(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /robots.txt
I20150618-09:17:52.484(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/fortawesome_fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
I20150618-09:17:52.489(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/mrt_footable/lib/css/fonts/footable.eot
I20150618-09:17:52.626(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/mizzao_bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
I20150618-09:17:52.632(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/mizzao_bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
I20150618-09:17:52.633(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/mizzao_bootstrap-3/bootstrap-3/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
I20150618-09:17:52.725(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /0045083fdb0aae9cfdd7bc8624d6d600f54d0f32.css
I20150618-09:17:52.784(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/fortawesome_fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
I20150618-09:17:52.848(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/fortawesome_fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
I20150618-09:17:52.909(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /packages/fortawesome_fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
I20150618-09:17:53.514(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:192) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) done downloading /81094d8fd7495646a6359f4dcfd57bd3f223ee39.js
I20150618-09:17:53.576(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/autoupdate.js:44) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) restartServer with location /data/data/com.idbzpo1upqh87wp5no3r/files/meteor/a2857e48230e176c2713f1a27f17feef6945ac58
I20150618-09:17:55.831(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/81094d8fd7495646a6359f4dcfd57bd3f223ee39.js:247) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (autoupdate_cordova.js) cordova.file.dataDirectory is null, retrying in 20ms
```

Comment: Is there any problem in Firefox OS, I think mup uploading Firefox img to server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through so much trial-and-error that I'm not sure exactly now which was the very final step before I got (and stayed) connected.

The final error for me was about the CORS XMLHttpRequest not being possible for "http://meteor.local", and at least one piece to that puzzle seemed to be helped by the suggestion in this thread about adding the browser-policy package: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4132

I plan to put all my notes together for a blog or at least comprehensive post as there are likely a lot of people that will run into some of these gotchas if they are developing (especially) on Linux for the Android platform.

Answer (score 0):

The app is simply updating itself. When the manifest's HTML, js and other file's hashes mismatch it will download an 'OTA update', similar to a hot code push.

You can see the download progress and what file is being downloaded in your log above.

Once the download is complete it will update the app's HTML and js files to the new version and restart the app with the new updates, keeping the route the same.

This is how Meteor updates the app without you having to push a new version up on the app store.

When the app is restarting it is running from scratch, with your previous localStorage settings (push state position and anything you may have saved). This is why the connection goes to `waiting` since it will be reconnecting to the server at this point.

It should be noted this happens only once. On the second load it will not do this until you change the code or do `meteor run android-device` again to push up a fresh APK to the device.

It may take longer to do this if you use `--debug` since the app's manifest will not match the one on MUP, which will be in production mode.

Comment: Thanks.  So this is normal then?  Even if so, I still can't make progress.  Since the DDP connection does not happen (or does not stay connected for more than a second or two according to the Meteor.status().status), the app is non-functional when connected to my server.  I cannot, for example, log in (using the ian-accounts-bootstrap-3 with accounts-password).  So maybe I need to clarify the problem a bit more.